# Fine Uploader- Server side code saves uploaded file but client displays 'Upload failed' message

Tags: fine-uploader

I have an MVC2 application where I am trying to use the Fine-Uploader plugin.  When I run through my code behind, it saves the file that I uploaded.  However, what get's displayed back in the browser is Upload Failed.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here. My code is below:

Code behind:

```
public void UploadFiles()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;

                        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentPath"]), filename);
                        hpf.SaveAs(path);

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Do something
            }

        }
```

Master page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Markup page:

```
<div id="manual-fine-uploader"></div>
    <div id="triggerUpload" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload now
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
            request: {
                endpoint: 'Home/UploadFiles'
            },
            autoUpload: false,
            text: {
                uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Files'
            }
        });

        $('#triggerUpload').click(function () {
            manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
        });enter code here
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Uploader expects a valid JSON response indicating whether the upload succeeded or not.

A successful upload response **must** have:

```
{ "success": true }
```

for Fine Uploader to know that it worked. You can add whatever else you want to your response, but without indicating 'success' Fine Uploader will think that the upload failed.

---

What I would do is add a return to your `UploadFiles` function. Somewhat like:

```csh
public UploadResult UploadFiles()
{
    try 
    {
        // ... save file and other things
    } 

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // failsauce :(
        return new UploadResult(false);
    }

    // success :)
    return new UploadResult(true);
}
```

Where `UploadResult` is much like:

```csh
public class UploadResult
{
    // This is important!
    public const string ResponseContentType = "text/plain";

    public FineUploaderResult(bool success)
    {
        _success = success;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // Here we create the JSON Response object,
        // set the correct content-type, and finally
        // it gets built with the correct success flag.
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = ResponseContentType;

        response.Write(BuildResponse());
    }

    public string BuildResponse()
    {
        var response = new JObject();
        response["success"] = _success;

        // ... maybe set some other data in the response JSON

        return response.ToString();
    }
}
```

There is [an example using ASP.NET MVC C#](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/ASP.NET%20MVC%20C#) up on the [server examples repository](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server) that may provide some assistance.

Also, on the development branch there is [a server-side README](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/server/) which indicates exactly what constitutes a valid JSON response for Fine Uploader.

Comment: I was just wondering, why is it that the file size displays on all browsers except IE?

Comment: The new [HTML5 File API is only supported by IE10 and greater](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compatibility). Without this support, it's impossible on stackoverflow. 

If you want some light reading, [here's a list of IE quirks related to Fine Uploader](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/limitations-ie.md).